# Opening new JPane on JButton click & call logic not working as expected

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to have a new JPane on JButton click & after that call another method. But the method logic is implemented first & the new JPane is displayed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == NextButton) {
        String text = userText.getText(); 
        panelContainer.removeAll();
        panelContainer.setSize(0,0);
        panelContainer.setSize(secondPanel.getSize());
        panelContainer.add(secondPanel);
        panelContainer.revalidate();        
        logic();
    }
```

}

SecondPanel is displayed after completion of logic(), but I want the other way.

Please suggest.

Comment: `revalidate` will post to the event queue for the EDT. If you want `logic` it to have a "happens-before" with the `revalidate` (while still ensuring `logic` isn't executed on EDT, you'll need to use `invokeLater` to post code to the event queue, but have your `invokeLater` spawn a background thread (or `SwingWorker` if needed) to ensure `logic` doesn't cause the EDT to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Try the method `repaint()`, it maybe work.